# Have trouble with verification result in Jupyter when run Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras

Ι have problem when type :

```
    import tensorflow as tf
mnist = tf.keras.datasets.mnist
(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train / 255.0, x_test / 255.0
model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
 tf.keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
 tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.2),
 tf.keras.layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax')])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
 loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy',
 metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=5)
model.evaluate(x_test, y_test)
```

The result should be like this :
[Using Google Collab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BbGDE.png)

But when I try using Jupyter notebook the result become like this:
[Jupyter ss1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nLkrz.png)
[Jupyter ss2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYDj7.png)[jupyter 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tq6kX.png)[jupyter4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6su47.png)

Comment: try to set seed to get the reproducible results (e.g. `tf.random.set_seed(2)`)

Comment: Just to be clear, you're unhappy that you have slightly lower loss and slightly higher accuracy?

Comment: @G.Anderson noo. sorry wrong screenshot. can you check my edited photo. before my verification result when i used jupyter there is 10000/1============= a lot of '=' but when i used google collab the '=' not so much. sorry for my broken english XD

Comment: @JayPeerachaisorry i dont get it T-T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm interpreting this correctly, you want to produce the exact loss and accuracy of the other model shown. Just FYI, this doesn't mean there is a problem with your model (evidently by your loss and accuracy values it is working rather well); no two models are likely to yield the same results, due to the optimising process of generating random weights and optimising them over a given number of iterations using your desired method.

As a previous answer has said, you can set a seed to reproduce the same results every time, using `tf.random.set_seed(<your_seed>)`. However, the original model you have included does not not include this line, so you won't be able to reproduce those exactly.

Comment: sorry, actually i just wonder why when i used jupyter before the verif result there value is 10000/1======= a lot of '=' but when i use google collab the '=' is same as my course modul

Comment: according to [this pull request](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/32286), this issue was resolved in version `2.1.0-dev20191108`, so you might want to check what TensorFlow version you're using.

As an alternative, you can use the `verbose` option in `model.evaluate` to disclude the loading bars, for example you could use `model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=2)` to use semi-verbose mode which should avoid this.